# How to reset rowData in a Ag-Grid that is using Update model == Transaction

Tags: transactions, ag-grid

I'm using the **Update model == Transaction** that allows me to add new rows doing:

**gridInstance.api.updateRowData({ add: dataToAdd });**

I have a RefreshMethod like this:

```
RefreshMethod () { 
 gridInstance.api.setRowData([]);  // deletes previous Data
 gridInstance.api.updateRowData({ add: dataToAdd }); // add new Data
}
```

That I use to populate data into the grid. The first time it is executed it works fine but after it's always adding new rows, don't clear the previous data, as it was supposed to do (setRowData([])).

Using debug tool I can see messages saying:

**"ag-grid: duplicate node id '5746' detected from getRowNodeId callback, this could cause issues in your grid."** 
**"ag-grid: duplicate node id '5747' detected from getRowNodeId callback, this could cause issues in your grid."**
...

This shows that the rows were not deleted properly

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

PS: This is how I'm getting RowNodeId:

```
this.getRowNodeId = function (data) {
  return data.stringId;
};
```

Comment: Not sure why you are getting issue. Could you reproduce it on plunk? also, could you try putting `gridInstance.api.updateRowData({ add: dataToAdd });` inside `settimeout` if it works

Comment: Hi Paritosh! Thank you for your feedback! I tried what you suggested but unfortunately didn't fix the problem. It's really strange because it only fails sometimes, kind of random behaviour!

Comment: I found the problem by doing some tests. It's necessary to bind rowData (add [rowData]="gridData" ) even if you don't use this property to update the values on the Grid, what is strange to me :/ That was the reason some grids were working and this in concrete was not.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by doing some tests. It's necessary to bind rowData (add [rowData]="gridData") even if this property it's not used to update the values on the Grid.

Comment: Hi Steve! It's been a while since this post :) At this moment we are using only binding to update the grids as for us it's enough ([rowData]="gridData"). The update grids with transactions is however a great functionality. At the moment I was expecting that because I was using this.getRowNodeId  to identify each node then when I will do gridInstance.api.updateRowData({ add: dataToAdd }) the API would replace the rows that I'm adding ensuring immutability but it seems it was not doing that that's why I received these warnings in console.